Can we know which time slot will be occupied by task continuation?
Assume Executor() is running on the UI thread.
void Executor()
{
    BadAsync();
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // E1
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // E2
}

async void BadAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); // B1
    Thread.Sleep(1000);     // B2
}


As Executor() does not await BadAsync() then B1 and E1 run simultaneously in the first second.
As B1 captures the UI thread then B2 runs on the UI thread too.
The following diagram shows there are 2 time slots x and y in the UI thread for B2 and E2.

Can we know which time slot will be occupied by B2?
Edit
Using a minimal example with MAUI.
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="start" Text="Start"/>
    <Label x:Name="stop" Text="Stop"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        start.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString();
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing() // analogous to BadAsync()
    {
        var d = 979; // in my computer 979 is the average of critical values
        await Task.Delay(d);
        Thread.Sleep(5000 - d);
        stop.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}

// Page.cs
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public void SendAppearing()// analogous to Executor()
{
    // others ...
    OnAppearing();
    Appearing?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    // others ...
}


When d is set to a value far below 979, the output starts with a blank window first and then switch to the following after several milliseconds.

In this case B2 is executed in SendAppearing() (or before SendAppearing() returns).

But when d is set to a value far above 979, the output starts with

first and then

after several milliseconds.
In this case B2 is executed outside SendAppearing() (or after SendAppearing() returns).


Non-trivial example
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = model;
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing() // analogous to BadAsync()
    {
        if(BindingContext is MainPageViewModel model)
        {
              await model.LoadDataAsync(); 
              UpdateUISync();              
        }
    }
}


Yes, it's gonna be x for E2 and y for B2.

you have to research the message loop and the synchronization context that posts to it. We have to return from Executor method before we can process B or something else awaiting us.

This whole question is a bunch of fallacies: B1 doesn't "execute" anything at all. It suspends execution of the current method for a time and returns an awaitable, which the threadpool posts back to the UI thread's message queue. So only E1 is executing, then immediately E2, then whatever called Executor all the way back to the message pump, then anything else in the queue up to the contination of BadAsync. So it's possible (in fact very probable) that slot Y will be filled by something other than B1, B2, E1 or E2, and also B1 doesn't actually execute as such (so there is no other thread).

If B1 loads data asynchronously instead of the trivial Task.Delay(1000). Is my question valid?

That code shouldn't exist in the first place. Trying to make assumptions on its execution order (regardless of if they can be made at all) are futile and even if it were possible to make those assumptions and prove them to be true, you would rely on an implementation detail of the runtime without it guaranteeing that exact behavior by contract. Not the best of ideas.

Most people said the non-trivial example is fine.

I can hypothesize that
First: B2 is always executed after E2.
Second: If B1 is shorter than (E1+E2) then B2 is executed inside Executor(). However if B1 is longer than (E1+E2) then B2 is executed outside Executor().

@DG, However if B1 is longer than - there is no B1 at all, B1 is in fact E1 time slot. As mentioned above at the moment of awaiting, method yields execution to the caller.

The only way to observe such micro timespans is to make statistical experiments, capturing timetraces with Stopwatch.GetTimestamp().

B2 after E2 looks plausible, though. Cause of internal mechanics lag of the state-machine.

B2 will run after E2.
Task.Delegate is just a wrapper around System.Threading.Timer. So your example would be converted to something like this:

void Executor()
{
    BadAsync();
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // E1
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // E2
}

SynchronizationContext context;
System.Threading.Timer timer;
void BadAsync()
{
    context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerElapsed, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite );
}
void OnTimerElapsed(object? _){
    timer.Dispose();
    if(context != null){
        context.Post(B2);
    }
    else{
       B2();
    }
}
void B2(){
    Thread.Sleep(1000);     // B2
}

Lets say we have threads available, so OnTimerElapsed will run 1s after the timer started. If Executor was called on the UI thread then context.Post(B2) will be called while the UI thread is sleeping in E2.
context.Post essentially just adds a message to a thread safe queue (the message queue) that the UI thread reads from. But if the UI thread is bussy (by sleeping) it cannot process any messages, so it first has to finish whatever it is doing, return to the message loop, process any other messages, and then finally run B2 when its message is processed.
This is one reason you should avoid running anything time consuming on the UI thread. If messages are not being processed the application will appear "frozen". So do not block the UI thread.
You usually want to be explicit in the order you run things in, by ensuring all async methods return tasks, and all tasks are awaited. This also helps ensures failures are handled. The main exception are event handlers, where you should make sure to handle any exceptions.

Task.Delegate or Task.Delay?

And timer and E1 run simultaneously, don't they?

@DG Yes, depending on what you mean by "running". Neither sleep nor a timer is really executing anything, the timekeeping is managed by the OS using lists and an underlying hardware timer.
